# How should feature requests/bug reports work on Meta?

Tags: support, meta, bug-reports, feature-request-process

On UserVoice, it's clear how the bug/feature request procedure works:

1. Enter a bug
2. Gain votes (or don't)
3. Get declined by an admin or get a bug fix

How will this work on Meta (this site? Is there any suggestion for this? I would like to see the status of my requests.

1. How should I tag feature requests?
2. How should I tag bug reports?
3. In what way are bugs handled?
4. In what way are feature requests handled?

Comment: If your question is closed, it's done :}

Comment: Jeah, but I don't know what's happening :)

Comment: Related, from an FAQ entry: [list of special tags on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/131713) agreed upon after this question was asked (and likely in part _because_ this question was asked)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are my thoughts

- Make sure the item is tagged [bug] or [feature-request].
- Moderators will review all questions with those tags periodically
- Moderators will apply **moderator-only tags** to the item to indicate its status

What are some moderator only tags we might need? Ideas:

- [status-completed]
- [status-norepro]
- [status-declined]
- [status-accepted]
- [status-deferred]

?

The only time to close is when the item is truly done and complete, forever. I suspect we will use the tags more often for that in case there is further discussion necessary of our "fixes" which sometimes are not so.. "fixed".. or have other related issues, etc.

Comment: The user tags are perfect, I would do this. The moderator tags should be documented in any way, probably in [meta-faq]? I'll post my question as CW, so this could be the collection for moderator and user tags.

Comment: Your list of tags is a good start. I would stick with them for the beginning. Start simple, more will be added when they are needed. Ok, I stop telling you the obvious procedure ;-)

Comment: I tagged it as "meta-faq" and CW so that it can be discussion and faq at the same time.

Comment: You should make sure that users can't create tags that start with [status-].

Comment: Although tagging as 'feature-request' or 'bug' will certainly work, I'm sort of hoping for an out-of-band method for handling the status similar to closing. However, as long as they're distinguished in some way (different color?) this could work.

Comment: what exactly does [status-norepro] mean?

Comment: @aug [tag:status-norepro] means that the bug can't be reproduced by Stack Exchange developers, hence can't be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

While moderator specific tags are a good idea, would new MetaSO-specific close reasons work better than (or at least in concert with) tagging? Closing as "No longer relevant" is a little vague, but closing as "New feature declined" or "Bug fix completed" is more informative.