# Where can we see the features that we will be added in the next update in the mobile apps?

Tags: feature-request, support, mobile-app

Is there a site<sup>*</sup> where the features which are being currently worked upon (for the mobile applications) can be viewed?

"What will the new features in the next version of mobile app be?"

This will avoid feature-requests on features that are already being worked upon. This will also increase the anticipation for the next version release!

Edit:

By site I meant a page/post (like the help pages, faq post), not a stack exchange site - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Sounds like Ask Different written all over it

Comment: Related or dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247173/what-is-stack-exchanges-workflow-for-handling-bugs-and-feature-requests

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a site where the features which are being currently worked upon (for the mobile applications) can be viewed?

Yes, you're already on it:

[image: Meta Stack Exchange]

See questions tagged [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app).

Comment: Only a small fraction of the feature requests are even considered. Most don't get viewed - or else they will be given a status. I want to see a official page where features that are being currently worked upon will be displayed

Comment: Among the considered requests only a very few will make it into the next app release. I am asking what features can be expected in the next app-release

Comment: @CRags There is no other "official page." The Stack Exchange devs' tools are actually integrated into the meta sites, and that's what they use for bug tracking, etc. (they also use Trello, but that remains private for obvious reasons).

Comment: Ok, so the answer is no, there is no single page where we can see what we can expect in the **next release**. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Upon reading my question, I understood why your answer was like that. Sorry for the wrong wording (error on my part). By site I meant a page (as in website) and not SE sites. Please consider answering to the question now

Comment: @CRags Yes, there is [a page here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app).

Comment: In addition of that, you could add the next version on the search query, e.g. ["1.0.84"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-app%5D+%221.0.84%22) for [tag:android-app], since current version is 1.0.83