# What tags do developers look through on localized meta sites?

Tags: support, tags, per-site-meta, russian-stackoverflow

I know that developers view questions tagged by [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) but what about other kinds of tags like [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [support](/questions/tagged/support)?

If not only [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) questions are viewed, why [we are asked](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4114/178988) to write only bugs in both languages - Russian and English. Does it apply to feature requests too? Or how developers differentiate which proposals require development and which don't?

Comment: TL;DR: bugs and feature requests mainly, but I do see replies on all other tags including support and discussions.

Comment: Could work like what us mods do - I've been informed of main meta posts concerning me, back before I was very active on meta, by other users. I do get notifications for my own site, but sometimes someone somewhere may go "hey, so this came up" somewhere or the other.

Comment: @ShadowWizard they are different as they are in other language and require more effort to understand the question. Updated a question.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It does not look like a duplicate to me. The post you refer to is about the workflow in general and does not include information for International sites. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky fair enough, thanks.

Comment: Its worth remembering until *very recently* - there's dedicated CMs per SO.local sites, or at least a CM who speaks the language (so someone in SO corporate should have a clue what's going on). However for bugs and feature requests, you're likely to have to eventually end up with the dev-team (who're mostly english speaking?) so having a bug report bilingual makes sense. FRs and such... eh, makes sense but I donno.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workflow itself discussed in the [What is Stack Exchange's workflow for handling bugs and feature requests?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247173/) (thanks [@Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard)).

Question about languages of a post: General idea here is that we want developers understand all information addressed them without somebody's help. It means if you want a feature-request gets implemented probably it's better to write it in English at least. At the same time not all users of an international site want/like/can discuss feature requests in English, so it's worth using the language of a community too (otherwise, probably, it's better to post a feature request directly on MSE).

I updated [the post on Meta Stack Overflow in Russian](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4114/). Now it covers [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s as well.