# How can I mark a feature request on meta as "won't fix" / "bad idea"?

Tags: support, down-votes, meta, feature-request-process

What is the correct way to vote for "won't fix" / "bad idea" for a feature request posted as a question on meta?

I didn't find this mentioned on
[How should feature requests/bug reports work on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/971/how-should-feature-requests-bug-reports-work-on-meta)

I'd imagine the correct way is to post an answer explaining why the idea is rejected if such an answer is not already there or, if such an answer is there, to upvote the answer.

I've lost more than 10% reputation for making two feature requests today and I suspect that's because the downvote button for questions includes "not useful". Granted, the pain is small for users with plenty of reputation, but for users with few reputation points receiving downvotes for a feature request that is not well received can deter them from making any suggestions on meta again.

Before making another feature requests to fix the downvote button tool tip, I'd like to make sure I understand the consequences.

Comment: There's always the [tag:status-declined] tag that is sometimes added. I'm not sure, but it might be the staff that add it.

Comment: *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.* as explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: What are you doing with your rep that 10 points is "hurting" you? I suppose it's quite annoying to drop under 125 rep because then you cannot downvote any more. And maybe the other point is 50 rep for commenting. But there is very little reason to worry about rep if you're beyond that point. Or below. If you drop from 100 to 90 then...so what? Same if you drop from 150 to 140.

Comment: @VLAZ As a infrequent contributor I was not familiar with the specific reputation thresholds that should be of interest to me but I have plenty of negative memory of occasions where my low reputation has hindered me to share my deep technical knowledge so that I paniced when I saw my reputation drop so much in a few minutes. The downvotes seems to have stopped now and the upvotes here more than compensate for the drop. All good.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ You need 1 rep to post a question or an answer. The minimum rep is 1. The only exception is protected questions (which are rare and probably don't really need new answers) which require 10 rep to post an answer to. Which is one upvote. If you have 100 rep, I wouldn't worry about dropping under the treshhold for answering protected questions.

Comment: @VLAZ I don't remember what exactly the limitations were, it's been a few years, but I certainly knew about the possibility of asking and answering questions, a key feature of the site. My newest example of frustration is a removed question that I suspect is an instance of "good title but hopeless question body" and I cannot check this, e.g. to learn what to do better when asking the question again (and answering it, I have a solution) as 10,000 reputation seems to be needed for viewing such cases.

Comment: @JoachimWagner: There *is* a way to see your *own* deleted posts without the need for 10k rep. Head over to your profile page. Under the "Activity" tab, look for the "Questions" subtab on the left side. Click on it and you should see a list of your questions. Scroll down and you'll see an option to view your deleted question(s).

Comment: That feature was [introduced on 2022-01-12](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/375078#375078) (*"All deleted questions/answers are now shown to their authors"*).

Comment: @JoachimWagner do you intend this question to be about posts tagged [tag:feature-request] in general, or about posts tagged [tag:feature-request] **you are the author of**?

Comment: @Luuklag This question is about the general case. How would it make a difference if I was the author of the question? (Also, the latter would be a strange scenario. Why take the time to post a feature request when one has to opinion that it should *not* be implemented?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are two separate things:

1. For "won't fix": [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

   > Indicates that the feature request will not be implemented, or that a bug will not be fixed at present time.

   This is a way for *staff* to indicate that they won't fix something. Since that's something only staff can do, it makes sense that only they* have access to this mechanism. We, the community, may be able to influence whether they bother trying to fix something or whether they slap a [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), but ultimately that's the company's choice.
2. For "bad idea": downvotes

   > **On posts tagged [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request), voting indicates agreement or disagreement** with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

   There is a [long-standing request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites) ([status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), incidentally) to change the tooltips to reflect this. But this is just the way it is, this is how votes are used.

<sub>*and mods, but they're trusted to not abuse it</sub>

Comment: Note that for well-written on-topic "bad idea" feature requests, if no answers that give your take/opinion exist, another approach would be to post an answer explaining why it's a bad idea, so people understand why you think it's a bad idea and can evaluate your opinion, and possibly, the feature request can be adjusted (can be combined with downvotes, of course), and if such an answer does exist, it's good to upvote it, so we have a clear understanding why people think it's a bad idea